# Optimal rate to scrape pastebin without having access to the api?

Tags: web-scraping, pastebin

As the title states I am trying to figure out the optimal rate to scrape pastebin without getting blocked from their archive page. Has anyone else figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem. In the end, I had to resort to having a single server responsible for collecting ID numbers once every 3 mins (that was about the rate at which we wouldn't miss any unless someone went crazy!), then created an API to expose those ID numbers so an external set of servers all running from different IP addresses could harvest the paste's and save them to the central db. The central script assigned serverID's to each id number in sequence so there were no collisions or repetition of scraping, the results were each 'slave scraper' paused a total of 4 mins between scraping, and the harvesting just managed to keep up with the ID collection. This didn't trigger pastebins annoying IP rate limiting. Be damned if I am paying for something I can get for free!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is what you mean, but the http://pastebin.com/api_scraping_faq API documentation says "We recommend not making more than 1 request per second."  Anything greater than that should be fine

Comment: I think you mean - anything less than 1 request per second - although it could be implied to mean - anything more than 1 second between requests.

Comment: In his title, the author mentions he does not have API access.

Comment: @serk Am aware, though referencing this could possibly be useful, if their site uses the same conditions to limit all requests sitewide.  good point regardless